# Keras multi-input model with tf.keras.utils.Sequence

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I am trying to train an RNN model in Keras to predict the next element in a sequence (e.g. given `[a,b,c,d]` predict `e`). Each element in the sequence has two components (lets call them `x` and `y`) of different shape and type, which is why I cannot simply concatenate the inputs. Therefore, I am using Keras's functional API to create a multi-input-multi-output model (given `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)]` predict `(x5,y5)`.

Furthermore, my training data is too large to fit in memory, which is why I have subclassed `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` to provide the data.

**My question:** How can I feed both inputs to `model.fit()` in such a way, that the model always receives the correctly corresponding `x`and `y`? This would have to work even if I shuffle the samples.

So far I've been thinking of two approaches:

- Create a single subclass of `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` that returns both inputs. The issue here is that I think for this to work, I have to create a single-input network and concatenate my inputs. As mentioned above, concatenating the inputs, however, is not possible.
- Create two subclasses of `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` that share a random state, such as a list of (possibly shuffled) indices. This way, when returning batches, both of them would consult this list on what samples to include in the requested batch and always return correctly corresponding `x` and `y`. This seems like a bit of a messy solution, though, and I somehow feel like Keras probably offers a "better way".

Comment: Create a single data generator that returns a training batch as a tuple in the form of: `return [x_data, y_data], [x_labels, y_labels]`. And the model should have two input and two output layers, not one.

Comment: That does sound great, thanks! To clarify: As a tuple of lists `([],[])`? Or as a tuple of two tuples `((),())`? Does it even matter?

Comment: As a tuple of lists, i.e. `[inputs...], [outputs...]`.

Comment: Thank! Your solution works great. If you post it as an answer, I will be happy to mark it as accepted.